# Hotkeys in Visual Basic 2010: one works, one does not

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I'm creating an "autoclicker" for use in video games that left clicks my mouse repeatedly at the push of a button. I want to have hotkeys set up that work globally without the autoclicker window being in focus. For some reason, only the hotkey that is meant to stop the clicking is currently functioning (F2). The F1 key is supposed to start the clicking, but currently the only way to start it is by pressing the Start button on the form manually. The code seems to throw an error when attempting to be deployed to version 4.0 of the .NET framework, but setting it to 3.5 solves this issue. I've included my entire code below because I can't figure out why the F1 hotkey is not functioning despite the F2 hotkey working flawlessly. Thanks for your time. A good portion of this code I came up with by looking at examples of other peoples' work, and I only understand it to a certain extent. I hope my code is formatted correctly because I'm new to this site and I don't exactly understand how to paste it correctly. Thanks for your help in advance, I really appreciate it.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vkey As Long) As Integer
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal dwflags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal cbuttons As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Dim hotkey1 As Boolean
Dim hotkey2 As Boolean
Private Const mouseclickup = 4
Private Const mouseclickdown = 2
Dim Test As Integer
Dim Interval As Integer
Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Click.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    Click.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub btnTest_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    Test = Test + 1
    Counter.Text = Test
End Sub

Private Sub Click_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Click.Tick
    Interval = CInt(timeTextbox.Text)
    Click.Interval = Interval
    mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    hotkey1 = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F1)
    If hotkey1 = True Then
        btnStart.PerformClick()
    End If
    hotkey2 = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F2)
    If hotkey2 = True Then
        btnStop.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub timeTextbox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timeTextbox.TextChanged
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Your declarations were for VB6.  The data types need to be changed for VB.Net as shown below.

Also, you need two independent timers.  One for detecting the keypress, which has to run at a high rate.  And another for doing the actual clicking, whose rate is determined by your TextBox value.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN As Integer = &H2
    Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP As Integer = &H4

    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Short

    Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, _
        ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, _
        ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

    Private WithEvents KeyTimer As New Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        KeyTimer.Interval = 50
        KeyTimer.Start()

        Click.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub KeyTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles KeyTimer.Tick
        If IsKeyDown(Keys.F1) Then
            Click.Start()
        ElseIf IsKeyDown(Keys.F2) Then
            Click.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnTest_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
        Static Test As Integer
        Test = Test + 1
        Counter.Text = Test
    End Sub

    Private Sub timeTextbox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timeTextbox.TextChanged
        Dim Interval As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(timeTextbox.Text, Interval) Then
            Click.Interval = Interval
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Click_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Click.Tick
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Function IsKeyDown(ByVal key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
        Return ((GetAsyncKeyState(key) And &H8000) = &H8000)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: To avoid the high rate Timer for detecting the keypress, you could use a low level keyboard hook via WH_KEYBOARD_LL instead.  It's significantly more difficult, though.  Google for it and you'll find tons of examples.  Another approach would be to register your desired keypresses as hotkey combinations with the RegisterHotkey() API.  This will fail, however, if the desired hotkey combination is already registered with another application.  It also isn't recommended for such common combos as simply F1 and F2.